# ArgoCD: How restart multiple Apps at once

Tags: kubernetes, argocd

My Database was down today and multiple applications in my cluster lost the connection with the database, but the Pod was Healthy (I know, I should have better Health Checks, but I don't). So, when the database was back online, the applications weren't able to connect again. So, I would like to restart all my Deployments. They share a label and are in the same Kubernetes namespace. We use ArgoCD to manage the applications.

In ArgoCD, I know I can restart all Deployments in one ArgoCD Application by typing this command:

`argocd app actions run my-app restart --kind Deployment --all`

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/user-guide/commands/argocd_app_actions_run.md

But I do not know how to restart the Deployment of multiple independent applications in ArgoCD. I tried, but none of these work:

```
argocd app actions run my-app1 my-app2 restart --kind Deployment --all
argocd app actions run -l mylabel=value restart --kind Deployment --all
```

I wonder how can I restart multiple applications in ArgoCD in one command?

I would like to use same syntax of the sync command (https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/master/docs/user-guide/commands/argocd_app_sync.md):

`argocd app sync [APPNAME... | -l selector] [flags]`

I tried to use sync, but it does not restart Deployments, unless I make some change in the Deployment itself (or if I use a configMap Generator, which is not my case).

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I created a shell script for my needs:

```bash
    for i in $(argocd app list -l yourgroup=your.label --output name); do
  argocd app actions run $i restart --kind Deployment --all; 
done
```

It will fail for those apps which does not have a Deployment, but, for me, restarted everything I wanted.

Comment: note that this is failing like this 

```argocd app actions run myapp restart --kind Deployment
ERRO[0002] Unable to create audit event: namespaces "mynamespace" not found  name=aggregation reason=ResourceActionRan type=Normal
```

I have tried this with argocd 2.4.14, 2.4.17 and 2.5.2
I also verified that this was with the appropriate rbac permissions